# Newton's second law: Showing that every non-constant orbit is periodic.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, periodic-functions

From the differential equation

> $m \ddot{x}(t) = -kx(t)$

I am trying to show, that every non-constant orbit is periodic, but I don't know where to start.

I am thinking about transforming the equation into radial coordinates, but I am not sure if this is the right approach or if it is even possible with only one equation.

Comment: Can you do it in case $x(t)$ is one-dimensional?  That is, $x(t) \in \mathbb R$ ... Of course it is important that $m,k$ have the same sign, otherwise you can get hyperbolic orbits.

Comment: @GEdgar do what? I don't have any information about the signs of $m$ and $k$.

Comment: With $mk<0$ you can get unbounded orbits, so you will not be able to prove this.

Comment: @GEdgar If $m$ and $k$ have the same sign, how should I approach this?